# Does uft8 mean size 8 font?

Tags: packages, fontsize

Does `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` specify the font to be size 8? 
I don't think so, but just wanted to confirm.

And if it doesn't, how do I determine the fontsize of my document when given the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{0em}{1.6em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: The standard font size is 10pt

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Do you want to typest a whole article in 8-point type (hugh!), or you just a portion of text?

Comment: It's best not to load the same package twice (amsmath & caption), by the way.

Answer (score 2):

`UTF-8` or `UTF8` is just a character encoding which has become the unicode standard nowadays. Specifying character encoding will declare which fonts to be used for printing characters. It does **not** have anything to do with the font size.

If you want to change the font size, you can write `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` into the preamble.

Comment: You could also mention the `extarticle` class, that supports font sizes ranging from 8pt to 20pt; whereas the standard classes like `article` have *direct* support only for three *main* sizes, namel 10pt (default), 11pt, and 12pt.